# How do I delete an application from azure active directory?

Tags: azure, active-directory

The title of my issue is clear enough by itself I hope....
I have only one application in my Applications list in Azure Active Directory. I would like to delete that, because it was only for experimental purposes.
But I cannot delete it, the delete icon in the drawer is greyed.

What can I do to delete the application from AAD?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

If it's a multi-tenant app, you need to convert it back to a single-tenant app before you can delete it. Please confirm that the setting 'Application is Multi-Tenant' (on the configure tab) is set to No.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Dushyant Gill! This indeed was the solution. Stupid that I overlooked that!

Comment: For non-native apps this is still an accurate answer using the new portal interface. Thanks

Answer (score 102):

For those coming by later and are using the new (preview) Azure Portal and are trying to remove a Native App;

The issue is due to the `availableToOtherTenants` setting, which you can not edit in the UI at the moment of writing. However, you can add the Manifest manually through the Azure Portal and edit the setting. After the edit, you can remove the app.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. It was exactly what I needed to get rid of the test instances that I had made trying to follow directions that ultimately were wrong (from the official MS Docs no less).

Comment: How did you figure out this?

Comment: @DawidFerenczy Search for a few hours and finally find something that looks like disabling multi-tenancy in your application as mentioned in the accepted answer haha

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to this - make sure that you are the owner of the application - if you're not, assign yourself ownership and delete will be enabled.

Answer (score 1):

**Unable to delete Azure AD due to Enterprise Apps (Delete grayed out)**

*Login to a Powershell (Admin)*

1. Install-Module -Name MSOnline
2. connect-msolservice 
   (Provide GA Creds)

**CAUTION: Following step may delete all the objects/applications recursively and may present multiple errors as well, but in the end, all this will help you to be finally able to delete the Azure AD instance successfully**

3. Get-MsolServicePrincipal -All | Remove-MsolServicePrincipal
4. Sign-out and Sign-in Azure Portal
5. All enterprise apps will now be deleted --> You can Delete Azure AD Directory now

Answer (score 0):

Whilst old, I stubmled across this issue earlier and found this post.

The portal has changed and none of the above worked for me (although I did not edit the manifest) - what I did do was go into AAD > Enterprise Applications and, from there, I could delete the Native applications.

Hope this helps someone (possibly me!) later.