# Cannot delete application on Azure active directory

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory

i am not able to delete application from azure AD  registered as on-premise application for SSO, each time i try it give me below error

```
{
    "errorCode": "MissingPremiumLicense_UnauthorizedAccess",
    "localizedErrorDetails": {
        "errorDetail": "User doesn't have Aad premium license."
    },
    "operationResults": [
        {
            "objectId": null,
            "displayName": null,
            "status": 0,
            "details": "User doesn't have Aad premium license."
        }
    ],
    "timeStampUtc": "2018-03-31T16:33:42.7151879Z",
    "clientRequestId": "03ada4a5-c617-4636-8636-133b53455014",
    "internalTransactionId": "d8b684d9-d2b7-4308-853f-03c3fc10df62",
    "upn": "gbadmin@orgdemo.ml",
    "tenantId": "3bed9924-d6ed-45f1-b666-d77ef6ba7bae",
    "userObjectId": null
}
```

it seems like its missing some premium license, how can i add that ?

thanks in advance.

Dheeraj Kumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using Pay-As-You-Go subscription with basic edition of Azure AD.

To upgrade to premium edition, click on Active Directory tab and select the directory > Licenses - All products and then click on the +Try/Buy option.

Refer to  - https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/cloud-platform/azure-active-directory-pricing

To delete the app check this link: [How do I delete an application from azure active directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27909846/how-do-i-delete-an-application-from-azure-active-directory)